# Toronto spider identification

Tags: zoology, species-identification, arachnology

I found it in Toronto, Ontario, during early June, 2015.

When prodded it seemed to jump around, or at least to move very fast.

I can also post a short video of it if needed.

[image: Unidentified spider.]

[image: Unidentified spider.]

[image: Unidentified spider.]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That jumping spider is a Jumping Spider! (That is, family Salticidae, commonly called Jumping Spiders).

There's a lot of diversity in the family, but your pictures look similar to the [Zebra Jumping Spider](http://bugguide.net/node/view/14618).